# Identify Broken Taillight

Tags: part-identification, tail-lights

Someone backed into my car and left a large dent. Luckily part of their tail light also broke off so I was hoping someone here could help identify the model of car to track down who did it. It is at the hospital where my fiance is currently at and there are not many patients here so it will have been someone visiting them, meaning they will probably be back so I want to know what sort of car to look out for. I'm located in Australia.

Outside of lense.

[image: This is it! Outside of lense.]

Pic of inside of lense.

[image: Inside of lense.]

Here's an image of the outside of my car.

[image]

Comment: Wow! This will be a hard one! At first I thought it might be a Volvo 850 https://community.foundry.com/discuss/post/295469 I'm not sure though.. the Volvo light seems to have some kind of dark edge that's not on this vehicle. Maybe "your" light is a little bit flatter also. The S70 had similar lights but they where even rounder I think. Also the light you have might not even be original...
At least it might be the same era of cars (or something completely different)

Comment: That does look very similar. Although the texture on the clear part seems to be a little different.

Comment: Does the hospital have cameras covering the car park? that may be the only chance you have. Perhaps it was some type of SUV / pickup... they have a vertical style back light more often than not.

Comment: Note: I've edited the images into the body of the question, along with the pertinent information. I then deleted the comments which are redundant. If I've messed something up, please edit the question yourself and clean it up.

Comment: Sadly no cameras as it's a small local hospital.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, this is just a guess, but I'd go for a Holden Rodeo 2002-2006; That's the closest I could find with a quick search

[image]

[image: Holden Rodeo]

Comment: Those do have the right texture, but the clear bit seems to large on these ones.

Comment: Yep, you're right about the clear bit. Maybe check other years of Holden utes, in case it was a stye change?

Answer (score 0):

You said it's a small hospital. Drive around its parking lot and look for broken taillights...soon, and several times a day, before the other driver gets around to fixing it.

Comment: or look for one dull'ish taillight and one bright new looking one.

Comment: I have been doing this every day.